# I have problems with the looping in list

Tags: c#

Making Lists of the student who have completed their graduation in 4 years and another list of student who took more or less than 4 years to complete their graduation and print the both  the lists by taking the entries form user.

I have made the list the code I used is also working but I used two foreach loop for printing the two lists but I want to use only one loop to reduce the length of my code. Below is the code I used as a beginner.

```
public void Print(List<Student> students)
{
    foreach (Student student in students)
    {
        if (student.Time == "4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed  graduation in 4 years : \n{student.Name}");
        }
    }

    foreach (Student student in students)
    {
        if (student.Time != "4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed graduation in more or less than 4 years : \n{student.Name}\t{student.Time}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have two different lists? And shouldn't you just print out the subject once and then list the students after it, rather than printing the subject for each student?

Comment: Can you please explain it more clear or the code you are talking about

Comment: I was only commenting on the fact that the first sentence says *"and another list..."*, indicating that you should have two lists. And also it seems like the output would be more readable if it said `People who completed graduation in 4 years: John, Sam, Mary, Steven`. Just personal preference, though. Also, you might consider using an `int` for the `Time` property rather than a `string`.

Comment: However, other than moving the subject (`"People who completed graduation..."`) to a separate `WriteLine` statement before the `foreach` loops, I think your current approach is fine. Using a single loop will not allow you to keep the 4 year students listed together.

Comment: OK Thanks I will try this way.

Answer (score 2):

To combine the statements and only use one foreach loop just use an else.

```
public void Print(List students) 
{
    foreach (Student student in students)
    {
        if (student.Time =="4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed  graduation in 4 years : \n{student.Name}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed graduation in more or less than 4 years : \n{student.Name}\t{student.Time}");
        }
    }
}
```

If you are after two list variables so that you can do extra logic use linq and .Where()

```
public void Print(List students) 
{
    var studentsIn4Years = students.Where(s => s.Time == "4");
    var studentsNotIn4Years = students.Where(s => s.Time != "4");

    // Do your logic here.
}
```

Comment: One difference with combining them is that the order will be different.  Instead of printing all the 4 year students first this will print them based on the order in the list.

Comment: Good point! Not sure if this matters or not for OP, but definitely worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public void Print(List<Student> students)
{
    var studentsIn4Years = new List<string>();
    var studentsNotIn4Years = new List<string>();
    foreach (var student in students)
    {

        if (student.Time == "4")
        {
            studentsIn4Years.Add(student.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            studentsNotIn4Years.Add($"{student.Name}\t{student.Time}");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed  graduation in 4 years: ", string.Join(", ", studentsIn4Years));
    Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed graduation in more or less than 4 years: ", string.Join(", ", studentsNotIn4Years));
}
```

However, if the number of student is not significant, I'd recommend thinking about simplicity and not pseudo-optimization and achieve that with LINQ like this:

```
public void Print2(List<Student> students)
        {
            var studentsIn4Years = students.Where(s => s.Time == 4).Select(s => s.Name);
            var studentsNotIn4Years = students.Where(s => s.Time == 4).Select(s => $"{student.Name}\t{student.Time}");

            Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed  graduation in 4 years: ", string.Join(", ", studentsIn4Years));
            Console.WriteLine($"\nPeople who completed graduation in more or less than 4 years: ", string.Join(", ", studentsNotIn4Years));
        }
```